# Relation between the types of convergences of sequences in $\mathbb{L}_p$ Spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

As far as I know there are 4 types of convergence in $\mathbb{L}_p$ spaces.

**1.** Pointwise Convergent a.e

**2.** Uniformly Convergent almost a.e

**3.** Convergence in Measure

**4.** p-Convergence

My question is how they are related? Are there any more types of convergence in Function Spaces?

Comment: I found the following super helpful when studying these: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much. These diagrams are really nice.

Comment: Can you please explain me the dotted arrows in the diagram ? What do they mean ? One thing I know is given p-convergence, there exists a subsquence which converges to limit function a.e.  
But what about the others?

Comment: The meaning of the lines is explained on the first paragraph under diagrams. For instance, a dashed line means that convergence in the mode at the tail of the arrow implies the existence of a subsequence that converges in the mode at the head of the arrow

Comment: Q. Are there any more types of convergence in Function Spaces?
A. Yes, look at my answer below. Besides the Cauchy versions, you did not have [almost uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Almost_uniform_convergence) in your list.

Answer (score 2):

I looked online for a single diagram picturing all the modes of convergence and couldn't find one. The only available one was mentioned in the comments and comes as separate diagrams. Back in my college days, my measure theory professor, Guillermo Grabinsky, handed us a handwritten version of the following diagram. All the credit goes to him, I simply used TiKz to type it and post it here.

[image: Modes of Convergence]

**Definitions**

- $(X, \mu)$ is a measure space.
- $p \in [1, \infty)$.
- $L^p:=L^p(X, \mu)$ and $L^\infty:=L^\infty(X,\mu)$.
- $a.e.$ := almost everywhere.
- $u.$ := uniform.
- $a.u$ := almost uniform.
- $\mu$:= in measure.
- $C.$ := Cauchy.

**Arrows**

1. $\longrightarrow$ Requires $\mu(X)< \infty$.
2. $\dashrightarrow$ Existence of a subsequence that converges in the mode at which the arrow points.
3. $\Longrightarrow$ Implication with no restrictions.